# Change height of iframe dynamically on tab change?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, web

I have a piece of code which I developed but there is a problem that i can't fix. The problem is that iframe dynamically takes height of content only in first tab but doesn't show anything in the other tabs.

```
<body>
    <jsp:include page="header.html" />

    <div class="container-fluid text-center">

        <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-top:120px">

            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                <li class="active">
                    <a data-toggle="pill" href="#projectOverview">OVERVIEW</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-toggle="pill" href="#projectPosts">POSTS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-toggle="pill" href="#projectThreads">THREADS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-toggle="pill" href="#projectMembers">MEMBERS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-toggle="pill" href="#projectTasks">TASKS</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="tab-content col-sm-12">
            <div id="projectOverview" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                <iframe src="projectOverview.jsp" name="iframe" scrolling="no" id="iframe1" onload="resizeIframe(this)" style="width:100%; border: 0px">
                </iframe>
            </div>
            <div id="projectPosts" class="tab-pane fade">
                <iframe src="projectPosts.jsp" name="iframe" scrolling="no" id="iframe2" onload="resizeIframe(this)" style="width:100%; border: 0px">
                </iframe>
            </div>
            <div id="projectThreads" class="tab-pane fade">
                <iframe src="projectThreads.jsp" name="iframe" scrolling="no" id="iframe3" onload="resizeIframe(this)" style="width:100%;border: 0px">
                </iframe>
            </div>
            <div id="projectMembers" class="tab-pane fade">
                <iframe src="projectMembers.jsp" name="iframe" scrolling="no" id="iframe4" onload="resizeIframe(this)" style="width:100%; border: 0px">
                </iframe>
            </div>
            <div id="projectTasks" class="tab-pane fade">
                <iframe src="projectTasks.jsp" name="iframe" scrolling="no" id="iframe5" onload="resizeIframe(this)" style="width:100%;border: 0px">
                </iframe>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <jsp:include page="footer.html" />
</body>
<script>
    function resizeIframe(obj) {
        obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';

    }
</script>

</html>
```

Please have a look and tell me where the error is and how to resolve it.

Comment: can you post a fiddle or something...

Comment: if i need to show that on fiddle i should change stuff like the src etc.The problem is that iframe dynamically takes height of content only in first tab.The rest of the tabs it shows nothing

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using bootstrap...

One problem with this code is that you did not wrap your columns in a .row. it should be written like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
[content]
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Another potential issue with the code could be the class ".in" that you gave the first iframe's parent div but did not give it to the rest. Most likely the only difference in all of those parent divs should be the one instance where you have the class ".active"

Comment: to give you a more detailed answer on exactly where the iframe issue is, it would be helpful to see the css. even more helpful to see the site this is on via codepen or fiddle

Comment: code doesn't work on fiddle for some reason. full source code is available here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1T6mmdh97BqBqizjQMT0iFzu2SHoSWIDn

Comment: Okay, I know it doesn't seem like the changes i suggested would affect the iframe loading but its very hard to pin point and correct one issue when there are many on the page. I would suggest adding your rows, correct the class "in" bootstrap does not have a class of "in" so you must of been trying to do fade-in or something else? Either way either take ".in" out of first or add it to the others. Once you make those corrections how your page behaves will hopefully tell more about why your iframes are not working, or possibly fix the issue.

Comment: If my corrections have no effect at all then I would start looking at the src of your iframes and make sure they really match up to the files. Your code looks correct (besides my first suggestions) so i don't see why it wouldn't work, must be some small technical error.